# How to get path and file name for import to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a demo.xlsm file with macros running automatically when I open the workbook but it needs to read a .csv file for data and a Lamda_Logo.png file.
The Lamda_Logo.png has always the same name.
The name of the .csv file is unknown but it will have the same path with my demo.xlsm

How can I use variables in VBA code to reference the path and name of my csv file?

I have tried

```
csvPath = Dir(Thisworkbook.Path & "\*.csv")
```

but it doesnt work.
The only command that works is

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Lamda_Logo.png"
```

to load the picture but I cant do the same for the .csv file since I won't know the name..

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imagePath As String
Dim imgLeft As Double
Dim imgTop As Double

Set ws = ActiveSheet
imagePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Lamda_Logo.png"
imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left
imgTop = ActiveCell.Top

'Width & Height = -1 means keep original size
ws.Shapes.AddPicture _
    fileName:=imagePath, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=imgLeft, _
    Top:=imgTop, _
    Width:=-1, _
    Height:=-1
    
     Dim fileName As String, folder As String
    
    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileName = "#Lamda_Dev_Projects_Risk_Register_191020211650.csv"
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A12").Select
    
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:T13")
 .Font.Size = 12
End With

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:T13").Font.Bold = True

Range("A13:T13").Interior.Color = RGB(147, 175, 186)
        
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
    
    'check for filter, turn on if none exists
  If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A13").AutoFilter
  End If
    

End Sub
```

Comment: `DIR` or filesystemobject would be a good start

Comment: So, try `csvPath = Dir(Thisworkbook.Path & "\*.csv")`, if it is a single such file (csv)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `Dir` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) will return the File *Name*, but without the *Path*.  So, if your workbook is "D:\Files\Testing\Workbook1.xlsx", and your CSV is "D:\Files\Testing\Data_20211020.csv", then:

- `ThisWorkbook.Path` will be "D:\Files\Testing"
- `Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv")` will be "Data_20211020.csv"
- The result you want for `csvPath` is "D:\Files\Testing\Data_20211020.csv"

As such, the full path will be

```
csvPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv")
```

(Remember that `Dir` will return a pseudo-random file that matches the mask/filter, and calling `Dir()` again will return another one, until they have all been returned.  If you have multiple CSV files, you might need a more specific filter, such as `Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data_*_Processed.csv")` or something)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation